# C# regex match, match.Success returns false even after following the rules

Tags: c#, regex, pattern-matching

Friends,
I want to match a string like
"int lnum[];" so I am trying to match it with a pattern like this

```
[A-Za-z_0-9] [A-Za-z_0-9]\[\]
```

but it does not seem to work.
I looked up rules at http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/46/CSharp-Regular-Expressions-Cheat-Sheet

```
string pJavaLine = "int lnum[]";
match = Regex.Match(pJavaLine, @"[A-Za-z_0-9] [A-Za-z_0-9]\[\] ", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
            if (match.Success) {
                // Finally, we get the Group value and display it.
                string key = match.Groups[1].Value;
                Console.WriteLine(key);
            }
```

the match.Success returns false.
Would anybody please let me know a possible way to get this.

Comment: Hi Russ,I have accepted most of them. Pls let me know whats to be done if the suggestions were not useful.

Comment: That's great! Don't worry - if the suggestions weren't useful then at least leave a comment to the poster; they might have a better suggestion and at least it helps people who browse the site in the future.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each of your character classes, like `[A-Za-z_0-9]`, matches only a single character. If you want to match more than one character, you need to add something to the end. For example, `[A-Za-z_0-9]+` -- the `+` means 1 or more of these. You could also use `*` for 0 or more, or specify a range, like `{2,5}` for 2-5 characters.

That said, you can use this pattern to match that string:

```
[A-Za-z_0-9]+ [A-Za-z_0-9]+\[\]
```

The `\w` is *loosely* equivalent to `[A-Za-z_0-9]` (see link in jessehouwing's comment below), so you can probably simply use:

```
\w+ \w+\[\]
```

Check [here for more info on the standard Character Classes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#WordCharacter).

Comment: When I was trying to parse "fun(int lnum[])"                      using                                                                            "    \w+\\(w+ \w+\[\]+\\)" , it is not returning true. Would you please let me know. Looks like I have followed all the rules.

Comment: @SaurabhGhorpade You are missing the backslash before the 2nd `w` and before each of the square braces `[` and `]`. There are some great regex tools that will help you get these right. Regex Buddy is one. There are online regex testers too, such as http://regexlib.com/RETester.aspx

Comment: \w is *not* the equivalent to [A-Za-z_0-9] bu default!!! Only if you enable RegexOptions.EcmaScript (which you probably don;t want). See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/20bw873z.aspx#WordCharacter

Comment: @jessehouwing You are correct, but I think that in most cases `\w` more faithfully captures the *intent* of using `[A-Za-z_0-9]`.

Comment: @Jay, if you want to match greek, arabic and other language characters as well, then yes. But if you want to limit yourself to ascii then no.